# Python IF statement to a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to put this code into a single line?

```
if x == 0:
   a += j["sum"] 
elif x == 1:
   b += j["sum"]
```

e.e. :D

*This is not a working example just for demonstration purposes*

```
a += j["sum"] if x == 0 else b += j["sum"]
```

Comment: You likely want a list that can be indexed by `x` rather than two separate variables `a` and `b`.

Comment: may I ask why you wish to do this? are you exploring the capabilities of python in which case this is a very narrow question or is it because you want to condense your code in which case it might benefit from restructuring your data, for instance `data[x] += j["sum"]` would work if `data` was a 2 element list

Comment: just because you can do something doesnt mean you should. Given the resulting effect of your if and else are two seperate things, its cleaner and more readable to leave it in the format of multiline. There is little to no performance improvment by having it on a single line other than it will confuse you or the next person to come look at the code after some time

Comment: Not certain, but try `a += j["sum"] if x == 0 else b += j["sum"] if x == 1`

Comment: based on the condition I need to add value to one or another parameter... but there are too many values and I do want to make it tidy...

Comment: `_=0; __import__("builtins").globals()["a" if x == 0 else "b" if x == 1 else "_"] += j["sum"]` 

Well, you did ask ;-)

Comment: But seriously. What I am suggesting (entirely tongue-in-cheek) that you do with the globals dictionary is what you could reasonably do with your own dictionary if you restructure your data in the way that @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen suggests.  Alternatively of course, stick with the original, which is perfectly clear and readable.

Comment: @yuuuu No, because `a += j["sum"]` is a statement, not an expression, and so can't be embedded in a conditional expression.

Comment: "there are too many values" means you should *definitely* be using a list instead of multiple variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way if you have Python 3.8 or later for the assignment expression operator `:=`:

```
(a := a + j["sum"]) if x == 0 else (b := b + j["sum"]) if x == 1 else None
```

but really the original is best. It's preferable that code is clear and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I may suggest you this one-line dual assignment:

```
a, b = a + (j["sum"] if x == 0 else 0), b + (j["sum"] if x == 1 else 0)
```

But you can also use **the old good semi-colon** to perform two instructions on one line:

```
a += (j["sum"] if x == 0 else 0); b += (j["sum"] if x == 1 else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly discourage it, but I guess one could use boolean true as the multiplication identity to do:

```
a, b = a + (x==0) * j["sum"], b + (x==1) * j["sum"]
```

This seems to work as I expect in a little loop

```
a=100
b=200
jsum=10

for x in range(3):
    a, b = a + (x==0) * jsum, b + (x==1) * jsum
    print(a, b)
```

Giving:

```
110 200
110 210
110 210
```

Answer (score 0):

While I would not code like this myself, one might throw caution to the wind and leverage `exec()`:

```
exec(f"{['a','b'][x]} += j['sum']" if x in [0,1] else "pass")
```

or potentially even better (credit to @wjandrea):

```
if x in {0, 1}: exec(f"{['a','b'][x]} += j['sum']")
```

Note, if you know `x` is always either 0 or 1 this would simplify to:

```
exec(f"{['a','b'][x]} += j['sum']")
```

Your pseudo-code solution suggests that might be so but your questions suggests it is not.

example:

```
a=100
b=200
jsum=10

for x in range(3):
    exec(f"{['a','b'][x]} += jsum" if x in [0,1] else "pass")
    print(a, b)
```

giving:

```
110 200
110 210
110 210
```

@wjandrea has suggested a nice improvement that produces the same results and is likely faster given the ability to bypass `exec()` if `x` is out of range.

```
a=100
b=200
jsum=10

for x in range(3):
    if x in {0, 1}: exec(f"{['a','b'][x]} += jsum")
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: I broke this second answer out per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269545/two-solutions-one-or-two-answers

Comment: For the first one, what about `if x in {0, 1}: exec(f"{['a','b'][x]} += j['sum']")`? BTW, I'm using a set because it's the most idiomatic way to check membership.

Comment: Ya, that seems like a nice improvement, though I'm not super keen on the one line if syntax being pythonic :-)  I'm certain it is more performant though